# Complex conjugate of the Dirac equation

Tags: field-theory, dirac-equation, complex-numbers, dirac-matrices, charge-conjugation

(Following the calculations done in 'Quantum Field Theory in a Nutshell' [Second Edition] by Zee, Page 101)

The Dirac equation in the presence of an electromagnetic field is given by:

$$
[i \gamma^{\mu} (\partial_{\mu} - i e A_{\mu}) - m]\psi = 0
$$

where $\gamma^{\mu}$ are the gamma matrices, $A_{\mu}$ is the gauge field, $e$ is charge, $m$ is mass and $\psi$ is a spinor.

The complex conjugate of this equation is given by:

$$
[-i \gamma^{\mu *} (\partial_{\mu} + i e A_{\mu}) - m]\psi^{*} = 0
$$

Zee defines:

$$
-\gamma^{\mu *} = (C \gamma^{0})^{-1} \gamma^{\mu} (C \gamma^{0})
$$

where $C$ is the charge conjugation operator. Zee states that you can plug this into the complex conjugated Dirac equation to get:

$$
[i \gamma^{\mu} (\partial_{\mu} + i e A_{\mu}) - m]\psi_{c} = 0
$$

where $\psi_{c} = C \gamma^{0} \psi^{*}$. When I try to do this I get the following:

$$
[i (C \gamma^{0})^{-1} \gamma^{\mu} (C \gamma^{0}) (\partial_{\mu} + i e A_{\mu}) - m]\psi^{*} = 0
$$

$$
(C \gamma^{0}) \cdot [i (C \gamma^{0})^{-1} \gamma^{\mu} (C \gamma^{0}) (\partial_{\mu} + i e A_{\mu}) - m]\psi^{*} = (C \gamma^{0}) \cdot 0 
$$

$$
[-i (C \gamma^{0})(C \gamma^{0})^{-1} \gamma^{\mu} (C \gamma^{0}) (\partial_{\mu} + i e A_{\mu}) - m(C \gamma^{0})]\psi^{*} = 0
$$

$$
[-i (C \gamma^{0})(C \gamma^{0})^{-1} \gamma^{\mu} (\partial_{\mu} - i e A_{\mu})(C \gamma^{0}) - m(C \gamma^{0})]\psi^{*} = 0
$$

$$
[-i (C \gamma^{0})(C \gamma^{0})^{-1} \gamma^{\mu} (\partial_{\mu} - i e A_{\mu}) - m]C \gamma^{0}\psi^{*} = 0
$$

$$
[i (C \gamma^{0})(C \gamma^{0})^{-1} \gamma^{\mu} (-\partial_{\mu} + i e A_{\mu}) - m]\psi_{c} = 0
$$

where I used the antilinear property $Ci = -iC$.

Now I have run into two issues. I am unsure of how to treat $(C \gamma^{0})(C \gamma^{0})^{-1}$ and also the sign of the $\partial_{\mu}$ term does not match the sign in Zee's expression. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The charge conjugation matrix $C$ is *not* an antilinear map. It is ordinary matrix with the property that
$$
C\gamma^\mu C^{-1} =-(\gamma^\mu)^T.
$$
(or maybe $C^{-1} \gamma^\mu C = -(\gamma^\mu)^T$. Conventions differ.).

Comment: Do you have a reference for the derivation of this property?

Comment: Also I don't think it solves the issue of the negative sign on $\partial_{\mu}$

Comment: Try http://hitoshi.berkeley.edu/230A/clifford.pdf or  my arXiv:2009.00518 article which is based on that.